# I'd like to know the usage of 'burst into'

Tags: word-usage

does the sentence "She burst out talking to me about her bad feelings." make sense? or it's not used in English?

Comment: Are you asking about *burst out* (eg "burst out crying") or *burst into* ("burst into tears")? The body of your question is different to the title. You can [edit them](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/463686/edit). Also, please say what research you have done.

Comment: It's awkward. The neutrality of the word "talking" clashes with the hint of drama you made when you use "burst".

Comment: In the US, the rules of spoken English are pretty loose. Since you are using "burst out" to describe her action, "talking" is unnecessary, also, put what she burst with closer to the verb.  It would sound more natural to say, "She burst out with her bad feelings to me."

Comment: We often "burst out laughing", but seldom, if ever, have I heard anyone say "burst out talking".

Answer (score 1):

Using that in the body of your question: **burst out**  [TDF](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/burst+out) idiom

> 5. To speak loudly and abruptly.

As in:

> I couldn't even finish telling my story before my mom burst out in
>   opposition.

And your sentence with modification:

> "She burst out sharing her bad feelings."